# If this day (today's date) the entry will count then tomorrow's date will start again in 0 got stuck in this syntax

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

How to code this?  If this day (today's date) the entry will count then tomorrow's date will start again in 0, I got stuck in this syntax.

```
Private Sub dashboard_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    load()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(str)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(customer_time) from customers_info", con)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmd = Nothing
    con.Close()
    total_every.Text = i

End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, don't repeat the same thing in the title and the question. Write a full and clear explanation of the problem first, then write a title that summarises the problem. So how about that full and clear explanation, because I have no real idea what you're asking for?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have data on my database. then sample today i want to count it using label toolbox assuming its 300, then tommorow i want my my label back to zero, then the 300 count will be add for my monthly entry

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit the question and add all the relevant information to it, addressing the issues I mentioned.

Comment: Something like `SELECT COUNT(customer_time) FROM customers_info WHERE theDateColumn >= CURDATE() AND theDateColumn < (CURDATE() + 1)`. Put in the name of the column with the relevant date. You should read about MySQL date functions if you need to get the month or similar.